# Custom Layout with angular for one component

Tags: angular

I would like to have a custom layout for one of my component (404 page)

I'm using [nebular](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/), not important but it's for more comprehension of my code.

Here the code of my `app-component.html`

```
<nb-layout>
  <nb-layout-header fixed> <app-header></app-header> </nb-layout-header>

  <nb-sidebar> <app-sidebar></app-sidebar> </nb-sidebar>

  <nb-layout-column>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </nb-layout-column>
</nb-layout>
```

As you can see, each component will have my `header` and my `sidebar`.
I want to know how to do for my 404 Component to not have the `header` and  `sidebar`

Should i have a variable `true|false` to know if i have to hide them ?
What is the best way ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is actually two options in here:
1- to hide those section when you are in the specific route. its easy to understand by angular router.
2 - you need to define a layout component then in your router give it to the parents who its children need to have it. then for those they don't need you should put them out of the parent's children.
take a look at this example: https://indepth.dev/posts/1235/how-to-reuse-common-layouts-in-angular-using-router-2